# File display in WebBrowser very slow with (some) networked files

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, unc

I have a Windows Form containing a WebBrowser, that I'm using to display PDF documents inside my apps. I have a Document class with a FileName property, and the WebBrowser's source is bound to that property.

However, with some networked files, the form can take about 30 seconds (up to 2 minutes sometimes) to display a single PDF file. The network share is hosted on an IBM iSeries.

The issue only happens in Windows 7 (on XP, the file opens instantly), and only once :

- User boots the workstation
- Launches the program
- Tries to view a UNC file : long delay
- Closes the window
- Tries to view the same file or any other UNC file : opens instantly

Any clues as to what may be causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling "detect automatic settings" in IE browser. I know this sounds odd, but I've had issues with clients accessing files over the network as a result of this setting!

Just a thought....

Comment: Odd problem, odd answer... I will check & try that.